# How to put a loop inside another loop

Tags: python-2.7, nested-loops

I am trying to make a loop inside another loop.  Below is code to loop through a series of questions and output the result as a string.  I also want to be able to keep asking the questions until the user breaks the loop and print out all text entered by user and also number them.

```
while True:     
    eventNub= raw_input("Enter event: ")
    if eventNub = ' ':
        break
    else:
        var1 = raw_input("User input 1")
        var2 = raw_input("User input 2")
        var3 = raw_input("User Input 3")
        var4 = raw_input("User input 4")

print('eventNub + var1 + var2 + var3 + var4")
```

What I want the result to be is:

1. var1, var2, var3, var4.
2. var1, var2, var3, var4.
3. var1, var2, var3, var4.
4. var1, var2, var3, var4.
5. var1, var2, var3, var4.

or as many times as the user does not break the loop.

Comment: Do you want to literally print `var1` or the value the user enters for it? Also, what do you want to nest? There's only one loop here.

Comment: Maybe OP wants to replace the `var...` lines with a loop.

Comment: The value of var1.  I can't figure out how to do the loop inside.  All my attempts have failed.

Comment: Do you want to print out each line as input is entered, or save everything up and then print at the end?

Comment: I want to save them and then print them out as a string later in the code.  I want to save the group of raw_inputs and string them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to break when you enter no value for your event number. 
For the out put to be printed later you need to save them in a list. Try this and see.

```
list = []

while True:     
    eventNub= raw_input("Enter event: ")
    if len(eventNub) < 1:
        break
    else:
        var1 = raw_input("User input 1: ")
        var2 = raw_input("User input 2: ")
        var3 = raw_input("User Input 3: ")
        var4 = raw_input("User input 4: ")

    list.append({'event':eventNub,'v1':var1,'v2':var2,'v3':var3,'v4':var4})

for each in list:
    print each['event']+'.', each['v1']+',', each['v2']+',', each['v3']+',', each['v4']
```

output will look like this:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if the output is correct:

```
count = -1
var = []
no_of_vars = 4
while True:
    count += 1
    eventNub= raw_input("Enter event: ")
    if eventNub != ' ':
        var.append([''] * no_of_vars)
        for i in range(no_of_vars):
            var[count][i] = raw_input("User input {0}".format(i+1))
    else:
        break

for j, var_list in enumerate(var):
    print(str(j+1) + ". " + ", ".join(var_list) + ".")
```

Comment: No it is not what I am looking for.  The loop never breaks and it does save the user inputs to print out later.  Thank you tho.

Comment: Hmm. How do you want the user to break the loop? This loop breaks the same way yours does...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have more simple solutions for your problem. I wish you like it

```
user_input = []

event_continue= True;
while event_continue:     
    eventNub= raw_input("Enter event Number: ")
    if len(eventNub)==0:
        event_continue = False
    else:
        var1 = raw_input("User input 1: ")
        var2 = raw_input("User input 2: ")
        var3 = raw_input("User Input 3: ")
        var4 = raw_input("User input 4: ")
        user_input.append(eventNub+"."+var1+","+var2+","+var3+","+var4)

for line in user_input:
    print line
```